# checkValidity returns true for last of many inputs when others are invalid

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm having some trouble trying to get a javascript function to validate all inputs with a specific class inside a form...

My js:

```js
function validateForm () {
  let isValid = false

  // inputs with the following classes are validaed
  const classes = '.form-control'

  // get all the classes to validate
  var inputs = steps[currentStep].querySelectorAll(classes)

  // if none of our classes are found, automatically make it a valid step
  if (inputs.length < 1) {
    return true
  }

  // create our function for validating the inputs
  var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(inputs, (inputs) => {

    // reset validation
    inputs.classList.remove('is-invalid')

    // if an invalid form, tell the user and prevent code execution
    if (!inputs.checkValidity()) {
      inputs.classList.add('is-invalid')
    }

    // is the current inputs valid or not
    isValid = (inputs.checkValidity()) ? true : false
  })

  return isValid
}
```

This function will be fired from a submit button inside my form, and there are several input elements with the `.form-control` class.

The issue I've got, is if I've got 4 inputs with that class, all required inputs and fill in the last of the 4 inputs `isValid` returns **valid** when the others aren't valid, how can I get `isValid` to only return **true** if all inputs are valid? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```js
function validateForm () {
  let isValid = true

  // inputs with the following classes are validaed
  const classes = '.form-control'

  // get all the classes to validate
  var inputs = steps[currentStep].querySelectorAll(classes)

  // if none of our classes are found, automatically make it a valid step
  if (inputs.length < 1) {
    return true
  }

  // create our function for validating the inputs
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, (input) => {
    const current = input.checkValidity();

    if (current) {
      input.classList.remove('is-invalid')
    } else {
      input.classList.add('is-invalid')
    }

    isValid = isValid && current
  })

  return isValid
}
```

I replaced `isValid = (inputs.checkValidity()) ? true : false` part with that:

```js
isValid = isValid && (input.checkValidity())
```

And set initial value of `isValid` to `true`.